# add form data as object into another object

Tags: javascript, forms, object

I'm having trouble getting form data into an object in the structure I want. currently it returns in this format:

```
mainObject = { name1:{}, name2:{}, name3{} }
```

what I am trying to achieve is

```
mainObject = { {name1:{}}, {name2:{}}, {name3{}} }
```

my js:

```
var users = {};

function formSubmit(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var age = $("#age").val();
    var zip = $("#zip").val();

    users[name] = {};
    users[name].age = age;
    users[name].zip = zip;
  console.log(users);
};
```

I have a bin available if that helps, thanks!

https://jsbin.com/bofohabahu/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: `{ {name1:{}}, {name2:{}}, {name3{}} }` is not valid syntax.

Comment: That answer actually pointed me in the right direction, thanks!

Comment: @JuanArciniega Your comment makes me think you solved the issue. If so, you should consider editing the question to reflect that, or mark one of the answers as accepted (if any of them are right), so that future viewers of this question don't waste time on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An object can be seen as a collection of keys and values. An object cannot contain a value (like an object) without also having a key for that value (think about it, how would you access it?).

So that's why `{ {name1:{}}, {name2:{}}, {name3{}} }` isn't possible.

If you don't care about having keys for each of the objects, then may I suggest using an array instead?  `[ {name1:{}}, {name2:{}}, {name3: {}} ]`

Comment: Thanks @jonahe. I ended up using your suggestion of using the array instead. This worked perfectly well for the project I'm using this for.

Answer (score 0):

this is how you make the `name` as a key containing the `age` and `zip`

```
    var users = {};

    function formSubmit(){
    var name = $("#name").val();
    var age = $("#age").val();
    var zip = $("#zip").val();

     users[name] = {

     age: age,
    zip: zip

     };
console.log(JSON.stringify(users));
};
```

try this 
https://jsbin.com/vanusapixu/1/edit?html,js,console,output